# can the number of null properties in elasticsearch document have some considerable impact when scaled?

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, null, scaling

We have a cluster with an index of doc type that can have up-to a maximum of 120 properties, but most of the time most properties will have value as null.

Will it make a difference in elasticsearch if we choose to drop the properties having null, instead of being updated with null values.

For example, Consider there is a doc with 5 property

```
{
  "firstName" : "Guna", 
  "lastName" : "Sekar", 
  "phone" : null,
  "email" : "guna.sekar@alkasdf.com",
  "country" : null
}
```

Will it make a difference, if we choose to drop the properties from being stored if the value is null

```
{
  "firstName" : "Guna", 
  "lastName" : "Sekar", 
  "email" : "guna.sekar@alkasdf.com"
}
```

is dropping the properties with null value from being stored will help improve something, for example

1. storage space
2. Overall cluster query performance etc..

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can drop the fields that don't have values and it will save some storage and may make queries a little more performant

the flip side is how do users that interact with this index know that a field that is missing implies a null value?

overall there's probably not a super high value in doing this, but you should test to see how it applies to your data and mappings and see if it's deemed worthwhile